# How to synchronize object with children arrays using AngularFire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Hello fellow Angular gurus!

I have a simple website with some galleries. The gallery names and content are saved in Firebase along with few other data.

I would like to synchronize the whole tree with Angular to allow admins to edit anything on the page.

This is how I sync it and it mostly works ...

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://profile-web.firebaseio.com/");
// create an AngularFire reference to the data
var sync = $firebase(ref);
// download the data into a local object
var syncObject = sync.$asObject();
// synchronize the object with a three-way data binding
syncObject.$bindTo($scope, "data");
```

... mostly.

What doesn't work is updating data. I think it's because the tree contains objects with arrays as children. AngularFire requires to use $asArray() to work with arrays. It filters out $$hashkey that gets added by Angular's ng-repeat and breaks the update process. $asObject() doesn't do that.

I tried binding the whole tree with $asArray() but since it's not an array it fails.

So my question: How do I sync the whole tree that is an object with arrays as children that have arrays as children themselves?

I have a working copy here
http://tr.tomasreichmann.cz/

Your time and effort is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Why does your object [contain arrays](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-arrays-in-firebase)? And why are we synchronizing the [entire data tree](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html#section-denormalizing-data) instead of just the collections we want to manipulate? AngularFire is a bindings library for synchronizing objects and arrays, not a local copy of your entire Firebase tree. Life will be a lot simpler if the data is arranged in a good NoSQL format as explained in those links. If there's a use case for this, explain it.

Comment: The data is organized in logical order and the project is small enough that it makes sense to download all at once and keep it synchronized as a whole. Synchronizing primitives is a pain with angularfire and I don't want to have to manually save each update. The 3 way data binding is quite usefull, but apparently it's useless for objects containing arrays. The arrays are there to maintain order. For exapmple galleries have images that have specific order. I didn't want to have to make so many requests, is there no other way?

Comment: When you say "edit anything on the page", what do you mean? Can the admin see every photo in every gallery at once and rename/delete/add photos and galleries from a single page?

Comment: If you look at the site http://tr.tomasreichmann.cz you can see these editable elements: The name, 3 main links (title, image, url, images in gallery), 2 links for CV (image, title, url). Each image in each of the main links has name, optional description and URL. All these should be editable. I understand that correct solution is not to make one request for the whole data structure, but to denormalize each branch and make for example link images in one main link separately to links url, link image and title. It sucks though. It's less OO and more relational, than I would like.